# How to get NodeJS client id?

Tags: node.js, session, socket.io

Running NodeJs I can see a sort of client ID:

```
debug - emitting heartbeat for client hg5ZurBEi8R3Ehf5kuBJ
debug - websocket writing 2::
debug - set heartbeat timeout for client hg5ZurBEi8R3Ehf5kuBJ
debug - got heartbeat packet
debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client hg5ZurBEi8R3Ehf5kuBJ
debug - set heartbeat interval for client hg5ZurBEi8R3Ehf5kuBJ
```

I am using socket.io. There is a way to get "hg5ZurBEi8R3Ehf5kuBJ"? A sort of app.session_id.

Comment: I think the question is not pretty clear. What are you exactly looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get it on server:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(socket.id); //client ID
});
```